# Following a recent post I made and was suggested to use A PRESENTER

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

Following a question I posted about a week ago, [WPF application using MVVMCROSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075098/wpf-application-using-mvvmcross), I proceeded to read about how presenters work. There is a lot of documentation and videos about how to do something with mobile apps, especially IOS but not a lot for DESKTOP Windows WPF Apps. Based on the N=24 video, I created a presenter that I derived from MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter and proceeded to override 
the function Present(System.Windows.FrameworkElement frameworkElement), where the main window would display my main view and all other views I would call, would display the its content under my main view :

```
  public class MyPresenter : Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Views.MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter
  {
    private Window _mainWindow = null;
    private MvxWpfView _firstView = null;

    public MyPresenter(Window mainWindow)
      : base(mainWindow)
    {
      _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public override void Present(System.Windows.FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
      //_mainWindow.DisplayGrid

      if(_firstView == null &&
         frameworkElement is FirstView)
      {
        _firstView = frameworkElement as FirstView;
        _mainWindow.Content = _firstView;
      }
      else if(_firstView != null)
      {
        if ((_firstView as FirstView).DisplayGrid.Children.Count > 0)
        {
          (_firstView as FirstView).DisplayGrid.Children.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        (_firstView as FirstView).DisplayGrid.Children.Add(frameworkElement);
      }
    }
```

My main view (called FirstViewModel) looks like this :

```
  public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
  {
    public ICommand BlueCommand
    {
      get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<BlueViewModel>()); }
    }

    public ICommand RedCommand
    {
      get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<RedViewModel>()); }
    }
  }
```

And my FirstView looks like this (in Xaml) :

```
    <views:MvxWpfView 
             x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.FirstView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Views;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
      <MenuItem Name="RedCommandMenuItem" Header="Red command" Command="{Binding Path=RedCommand}" />
      <MenuItem Name="BlueCommandMenuItem" Header="Blue command" Command="{Binding Path=BlueCommand}" />
    </Menu>
    <Grid Name="DisplayGrid" Grid.Row="1">
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

After that, I made my presenter the one to use instead of the default and was able to display the view with the red background and the one with the blue background from my main view which contains the MENUS. So this would essentially work very well with what I want to do.

So where am I going with this?? What I am wondering is, this is very different from all the other examples I have seen that would use the presenter's SHOW METHOD where you have a Model requested and you need to use Mvx.Resolve to get the view created.. The Show method is not available to be overrided with both MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter and MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter classes. By calling the commands, ShowViewModel calls upon the Presenter (I presume) to display my new view but I need not to call upon Resolve here as I get the FrameworkElement.. So where is the resolve being done and by whom? I am trying to understand the mechanics behind in order to debug this better should I have a problem.. And is there any link with the CONTAINER mentionned in the previous post?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So where is the resolve being done and by whom?

This is being done in the base `MvxWpfViewPresenter`

```
public abstract class MvxWpfViewPresenter
    : IMvxWpfViewPresenter
{
    public void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var loader = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxSimpleWpfViewLoader>();
            var view = loader.CreateView(request);
            Present(view);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MvxTrace.Error("Error seen during navigation request to {0} - error {1}", request.ViewModelType.Name,
                           exception.ToLongString());
        }
    }

    public abstract void Present(FrameworkElement frameworkElement);

    public virtual void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        MvxTrace.Warning("Hint ignored {0}", hint.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Views/MvxWpfViewPresenter.cs

`Show` should probably be `virtual` in this class - but it's a very simple class and I always expected WPF users would just write their own versions of `IMvxWpfViewPresenter`

> is there any link with the CONTAINER mentionned in the previous post?

The default container for WPF is:

```
public class MvxWpfViewsContainer
    : MvxViewsContainer
    , IMvxWpfViewsContainer
{
    public FrameworkElement CreateView(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var viewType = GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);
        if (viewType == null)
            throw new MvxException("View Type not found for " + request.ViewModelType);

        // , request
        var viewObject = Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
        if (viewObject == null)
            throw new MvxException("View not loaded for " + viewType);

        var wpfView = viewObject as IMvxWpfView;
        if (wpfView == null)
            throw new MvxException("Loaded View does not have IMvxWpfView interface " + viewType);

        var viewControl = viewObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (viewControl == null)
            throw new MvxException("Loaded View is not a FrameworkElement " + viewType);

        var viewModelLoader = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
        wpfView.ViewModel = viewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(request, null);

        return viewControl;
    }
}
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Views/MvxWpfViewsContainer.cs

It inherits from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Views/MvxViewsContainer.cs - which is shared across all platforms.

During Setup, the container is filled with View `Type`s using Reflection - see `InitalizeViewLookup` info in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#wiki-overriding-view-viewmodel-associations

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and your help. What I meant by LINK was not a link to the container code per say, but a CONNECTION with the container and what I was saying before. Sorry, wrong choice of words.

Comment: The container is the `IMvxSimpleWpfViewLoader` used in the base presenter code in my answer - see the interface inheritance https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/b1cb973062b2eb8149f0934f331c4006bc61fa3c/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Views/IMvxWpfViewsContainer.cs#L12